# Historical data for total market capitalization

Tags: data, market, market-capitalization, total

I'm working on a data analytics certificate and need historical data on the total market capitalization for the US for a course project. Can anyone suggest a source?

Comment: The world bank has this data for many countries https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/CM.MKT.LCAP.CD download the Excel spreadsheet and then find the row (row 254 I believe) for the United States. It starts in 1980.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!